# I cannot sign in to App Store with my Apple ID

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I created a new Apple ID and verified it. In the App Store, when I want to update or upgrade my OS X, it is asking me to sign in to download. I try to sign in but I cannot — there is no error or warning. I click sign in button and the sign in button appears again.

I tried to reinstall OS X but during the reinstall I am asked for my Apple ID and clicking the sign in button has no action and I am asked to sign in again.

What is the problem?

Comment: Reset your Apple ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created a new Apple ID, you need to have a valid OS X purchase  under this new Apple ID? Otherwise you might have to use—at least for the install—the Apple ID you used to buy OS X.

Comment: I've tried to make this non-answer into an answer, but feel free to edit if you feel I've lost clarity.

Comment: @FLIR31207 thanks, i didn't know that. I am already using my mac with valid os x, why i have to buy again? Anyway, i understood.